# Matlab: Block Tridiagonal with Non-Square Vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to create a diagonal matrix using the following matrix as the diagonal

```
base = [a b c d e f 0;
        0 g h i j k l];
```

I need the resulting matrix to look like this...

```
[a b c d e f 0 0 0;
 0 g h i j k l 0 0;
 0 0 a b c d e f 0;
 0 0 0 g h i j k l];
```

except it needs to be "n" elements tall

I have tried using the `kron` function, but it shifts each consecutive row too many elements to the right.

How can I accomplish what I need in a way where I can select `n` arbitrarily?

Comment: Is `n` always even? Or do you consider the matrix you showed to be `2` tall?

Comment: Why are there so many matlab homework questions on SO with no attempted code?

Comment: show what you tried with `kron`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it pretty fast with a 2D convolution:

```
n = 4; %// desired number of rows in result. Should be a multiple of size(base,1)
T = eye(n-1);
T(2:size(base,1):end,:) = 0;
result = conv2(base,T);
```

Example: with

```
base =

    0.7497    0.3782    0.4470    0.5118    0.6698    0.3329         0
         0    0.9850    0.5638    0.9895    0.4362    0.4545    0.8578
```

and `n=4` the result is

```
result =

    0.7497    0.3782    0.4470    0.5118    0.6698    0.3329         0         0         0
         0    0.9850    0.5638    0.9895    0.4362    0.4545    0.8578         0         0
         0         0    0.7497    0.3782    0.4470    0.5118    0.6698    0.3329         0
         0         0         0    0.9850    0.5638    0.9895    0.4362    0.4545    0.8578
```

Comment: +1: nice! Although my solution seems to scale a lot better for large `n`...It would seem that `conv2` is O(n²), or at least super-linear...is that true?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks! Yes, I would bet it's at least super-linear. But I haven't tested

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use repeated out-of-bounds assignment. MATLAB will automatically pad any missing entries with `0` in those cases. Here's how:

```
%// Some test variables
a = rand;  g = rand;
b = rand;  h = rand;
c = rand;  i = rand;
d = rand;  j = rand;
e = rand;  k = rand;
f = rand;  l = rand;

%// base matrix
base = [
    a b c d e f 0;
    0 g h i j k l];

%// use out-of-bounds assignment 
n = 3;
output = base;
for ii = 1:n
    output(end+1:end+size(base,1), size(base,1)*ii+1:end+size(base,1)) = base;
end
```

The hard way is the faster way (relevant for when `n` is large and/or you need to repeat this very often). Figure out the pattern behind which indices would be filled in the final matrix by which values in the original matrix, then generate a list of those indices and assign those values to those indices:

```
[b1,b2]      = size(base);
[ii,jj,vv]   = find(base);
inds         = bsxfun(@plus, (ii + (n+1)*b1*(jj-1)).', (0:n).'*b1*(1 + (n+1)*b1));
output       = zeros( (n+1)*b1, b2+n*b1 );
output(inds) = repmat(vv.', n+1, 1)
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out what happens here exactly :)